# Quartz CronTrigger - fire time

Tags: java, cron, quartz

I`m using quartz cron expression to build n schedule events, i have a start date and end date, but, when a crate a expression, the second event (getNextValidTimeAfter) its wrong...

1. 08-03-19 08:00:00 -- first date
2. 05-04-19 08:00:00 -- wrong date...
3. 05-07-19 08:00:00
4. 04-10-19 08:00:00

Follow the expression

0 0 8 ? 1/3 FRI#1 *

```
  org.quartz.CronExpression expression = new org.quartz.CronExpression(cronExpression.getExpression());

    List<Schedule> scheduleList = new ArrayList<>();

    Date nextExecutionDate = cronExpression.getStartDate();

    boolean first = true;

    while (true) {

        Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
        schedule.setStatus(Enums.StatusSchedule.PROGRAMADO);
        schedule.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
        schedule.setServiceOrderType(cronExpression.getServiceOrderType());
        schedule.setEstimatedTime(cronExpression.getEstimatedTime());

        if (first == false)
            nextExecutionDate = expression.getNextValidTimeAfter(nextExecutionDate);
        else
            first = false;

        if (cronExpression.getEndDate().compareTo(nextExecutionDate) <= 0)
            break;

        schedule.setScheduleDate(nextExecutionDate);

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(schedule.getScheduleItems()))
            schedule.setScheduleItems(new ArrayList<>());

        for (GenericShelfData genericShelfData : genericShelfDataList) {

            ScheduleItem scheduleItem = new ScheduleItem();
            scheduleItem.setStatus(Enums.StatusSchedule.PROGRAMADO);
            scheduleItem.setSchedule(schedule);
            scheduleItem.setGenericShelfData(genericShelfData);
            scheduleItem.setScheduleSeparate(Enums.YesOrNo.NAO);
            schedule.getScheduleItems().add(scheduleItem);
        }

        scheduleList.add(schedule);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My expression was wrong... The correct is.. 0 0 8 ? 3/3 FRI#2 *

I use this site for build a expression: https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html